# Не срабатывает focus

Tags: html, css, меню, focus

Суть простая, при клике на иконку меню должен выпадать список, во всяком случае так казаться :) Подсмотрел технику в одном уроке, но что-то не сработало.

```
.menu:focus .dropdown{
display: block;
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;
display: none;
}

<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu"></button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правильно указали имя элемента. Что бы указать элемент, который находиться на одном уровне, нужно ставить `~`

```css
.menu:focus ~ .dropdown{
display: block;
}

.main-head .dropdown{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 85px;
right: 210px;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">      
    <div id="logo">
        <p>Smart</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button menu">Кнопка</button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Menu4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А я то думал..)